# Microsoft Graph -- Get user locale / language

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We want to get the locale / language of a Microsoft Graph user.

We're trying to use [mailBoxSettings/language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and while for us it works fine, it appears that for a large proportion of our customer's users, there is no language / locale when fetching the information.

Is this normal behavior? Wouldn't any user that has used Outlook at least once have a language field populated?

What would be a better way to get the user's language, hopefully without asking for more scopes?

Comment: Yes, if preferred language is null it will come as null for [Get Locale/Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Thanks @Trinetra-MSFT. It appears this happens often. Is there a reliable way to get a user's language in this case? When a user's preferred language is null, does that mean all of the Microsoft services used by said user are in English? I'm assuming if what is returned is null, then Microsoft Graph itself does not have the information.

Comment: if preferred language is null you can use the language, locale itself